# Get registered custom fields or post meta even if empty

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I would like to be able to get all registered custom fields or post meta for a given post.

The limitation I am facing is that the use of either `get_post_meta` or `get_post_custom` returns an array of the fields that are not empty. Empty fields are ignored.

Is there a workaround for getting all the fields registered by a theme or by a plugin even if they are empty? I understand that this is probably impossible since empty fields do not have any records in the database, but I would very much appreciate a confirmation before I abandon this altogether..

Thanks a lot,
Harry